# How to get nav to show current_page_parent class when on regular post (not blog), differentiated by category

Tags: categories, single

In order to highlight menu item when viewing single post (not blog), am trying to add special classes to single, (regular, not custom) posts from different categories. this is the basic code:

```
function my_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {
  if ( is_single() &&  (in_category('workshops') ) {
    $classes[] = 'special-class';
  }
  return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_special_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

its not working. the (is_category('workshops') piece is not quite right. works as expected when only

```
      if ( is_single() ) {
```

please correct! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct syntax is:

```
    if ( is_single() && in_category ( '5' )  ) {
```

However,  I solved the problem using this code:

```
//add category classes to single.php
add_filter('body_class','add_category_to_single');
function add_category_to_single($classes, $class) {
    if (is_single() ) {
        global $post;
        foreach((get_the_category($post->ID)) as $category) {
            // add category slug to the $classes array
            $classes[] = $category->category_nicename;
        }
    }
    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;
}
```

(or you could try using a plugin such as: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ambrosite-body-class-enhanced/). From there, you can style with css.

Comment: Good job. You should edit your post to include the code that proved to be your solution.

Comment: You may not have been able to edit yet so I included the code. If it's not correct and you are unable to edit then comment.

Comment: thanks Ryan! I hope this helps someone else not spend hours figuring it out like I did!

Comment: Be sure to use `in_category ( '5' )` in your conditional statement (if you didn't) so the foreach loop doesn't run the get_the_category query to the database on every single post.

Comment: I just edited code to reflect what I am using. And actually, I need to run it on every post, bc I have 3 categories corresponding to 3 different nav items: Workshops, Tutorials and Blog.

Comment: You should be able to use an array to specify 3 categories if you want. Otherwise, if it works, it works! I'm just being nitpicky.

Answer (score 0):

Use `in_category( $category )` and `is_category( $category )` in your conditional statement.

`in_category( $category )` - Check if the current page is associated with a category.

`is_category( $category )` - Check if the current archive is associated with a category.

Example:
`if ( in_category( 'workshops' ) || is_category( 'workshops' ) ) {`

See:
[Function Reference/in category « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category)
[Function Reference/is category « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category)

Comment: thank you. see edits above: I believe in_category is what I need, but still not working yet.